# RubyMine reports Xvfb not found on your system (Headless::Exception)

Tags: rubymine, capybara-webkit

Using Rubymine 4.0.1 I get the following error running my capybara-webkit tests. I can run these tests fine from command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) states that you need to install Xvfb:

> If you're like us, you'll be using capybara-webkit on CI.
>
> On Linux platforms, capybara-webkit requires an X server to run, although it doesn't create any visible windows. Xvfb works fine for this. You can setup Xvfb yourself and set a DISPLAY variable, or try out the [headless gem](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless).

You didn't specify the OS that you are using, but here is the [installation guide for CentOS](http://opensourcetester.co.uk/2011/06/23/capybara-webkit-centos/) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

check for the RubyMine version...I was also facing same issue...but after 1 weeks research I discovered that Rubymine 5.4.4 has this issue...then I switched back to 5.4.1...And it starts working :)